# Which RDP client have possibility to mount disks from client PC?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, rdp, tsclient

Until Ubuntu 11.10 came out Terminal Server Client in Ubuntu 11.04 offered the possibility of mounting hard drives from client side.

I just wonder if there is such client that offer such possibility.

I tried Remotedesktop Client, Remmina Desktop Client, and Remote Desktop Viewer. They are all lack of this function?

I really need it to use files from my Ubuntu PC on Windows Server 2003 PC downstairs from RDP client on Ubuntu 11.10.

Please help.

Regards.
HelpNeeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have found out, Remmina can set up one folder as a mounted folder to the remote desktop. The solution is that the whole FileSystem has to mount to individually added remote desktop to access all files on the computer from which we are connecting. This is great! It will show all external drives, such as Flash drives and external HDDs.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried **rdesktop** from command line. To mount your local hard drives you can use **rdesktop with -r option** command ... It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

try [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsclient/). the download is there, butI don't know if it is for linux